# Great Plains eConnect Issue, FileNotFoundException... what am I missing?

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-gp, econnect

I am trying to invoke a call to Dynamics Great Plains, and am getting a very frustrating error.

I call the code:

```
eConnectMethods eConCall = new eConnectMethods();
```

and I immediately trap the following:

```
ERROR
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.Thunk.Proxy.CoCreateObject(Type serverType, Boolean bQuerySCInfo, Boolean& bIsAnotherProcess, String& uri)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponentProxyAttribute.CreateInstance(Type serverType)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.IsCurrentContextOK(RuntimeType serverType, Object[] props, Boolean bNewObj)
```

... and then referencing my assembly at the line above.

Can someone tell me what the eConnect object is looking for, and how I can get it working?

Comment: Consider using sysinternals [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see which file is missing

Comment: Okay, when I was having trouble with getting the eConnect library to behave, I found that there are a ton of fiddly, little settings involved. Two things I found to help. First, ensure your connection string is valid. Second, make sure Integration Manager is installed and working. Turns out that the recent version of Integration Manager uses eConnect so if it's working, your libraries should as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up restarting from scratch and I was unable to reproduce the error.  Sigh.